# Remove user's ability to disable lockscreen in Gnome 2

Tags: 12.04, gnome, lock-screen, xml, gnome2

How do I remove the "Lock" on/off toggle from Gnome 2's Brightness and Lock screen under System Settings? I need to remove our staff's ability to disable their lock screen by using the toggle.

[image: Brightness and Lockscreen Image]

In the past I was able to modify the xml file named screen.ui located in the /usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/ to remove any screen timeout option's higher than 10 minutes, but this seems less straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty easy and involved changing a flag from "True" to "False" in the screen.ui file under the "screen_lock_on_switch" section. After I logged out and back in the Lock toggle button was gone.

Code before modification

```
                          <object class="GtkSwitch" id="screen_lock_on_switch">
                            <property name="visible">True</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                            <accessibility>
                              <relation type="labelled-by" target="lock-section-heading"/>
                            </accessibility>
                          </object>
```

Code after modification

```
                          <object class="GtkSwitch" id="screen_lock_on_switch">
                            <property name="visible">False</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                            <accessibility>
                              <relation type="labelled-by" target="lock-section-heading"/>
                            </accessibility>
                          </object>
```